# What do I do with a post like this?

Tags: discussion, support, help-vampire

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402145/http-post-request-bot-with-a-proxy-list/28402316

I made the stupid mistake of answering, and now I am getting asked to hand hold, and it appears that the poster has no intention of actually trying to learn and only posted this because of some nefarious purpose. (of which it appears that due to ignorance I have not helped him achieve.)

But on that note I actually do think that the answer I posted has merit...

Soo.... what do I do ?

Comment: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to keep helping, don't.

If you do, don't do it in the comments, as that can get messy; if you want to continue a conversation that can ago off on many tangents, use [chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com).

Otherwise, don't worry about it and move on. If they really need help, they'll ask another question or figure it out on their own. It's good to help users out as much as you can, but you're providing your time and knowledge for free here, so you have the say as to when that stops.

If a question starts to drift or it becomes evident that a lot of basic knowledge is lacking, feel free to use chat to clear things up, or simply leave and ignore subsequent requests.

Comment: For me I feel as if its a combination of lack of basic knowledge, unwillingness to google it himself, and wanting a complete solution provided, and a less than innocent purpose. (if the first 3 items were there then I could let the last one slide. ) 

I think I will just attempt to ignore it, although I have gotten a few notifications so far, is there a way to unfollow a thread ?

Comment: @DamianNikodem Unfortunately, [no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142281/is-there-a-way-to-unfollow-notifications-on-a-particular-post).

Comment: @DamianNikodem You can't "unsubscribe" from your own answer. But if you want, we can nuke the whole question. (though you'll lose the rep you gained on it)

Comment: @DamianNikodem Just ignore the post for a little while... If the comments continue, flag them. Also if you really want to you can ask to have the post to be [disassociated from your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)